# SS OrmLite: Ambiguous column name when joining and filtering on the column name

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have two tables (code first) which shares a common column name "Status", which incidentally is used in a Where clause.

This results in the *ambiguous column* error.

```
var q = db.From<Process>()
.Where<Process>(p => Sql.In(p.Status, enProcessStatus.READY, enProcessStatus.ACTIVE))
.Join<Activity>()

db.SelectMulti<Process,Activity>(q);
```

While I'm using `SelectMulti`, the error also appears with a regular `Select` (just for debugging purposes).

I have found that it is the Where clause that's causing the problem, since it filters on the  column with the same name in both tables. I have tried *not* using the `Sql.In`, which doesn't help.

Inside C# there is no ambiguity to which object I'm referring to, the compiler knows it's the *Process* and not the *Activity*, but when it comes to the SQL it doesn't work anymore.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always specify your joins at the start of your query, I.e. immediately after `From<T>()`:

```cs
var q = db.From<Process>()
  .Join<Activity>()
  .Where<Process>(p => Sql.In(p.Status, enProcessStatus.READY));

var results = db.SelectMulti<Process,Activity>(q);
```